# Why is twitter bootstrap's typeahead not working here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get typeahead.js working in my project.  I have bootstrap loaded in my project (downloaded the source from the bootstrap site just now).  Looking in the source shows no mention of typeahead, so I included the standalone js file.

I'm not getting any errors when I try to use it, but it's just not working.  Simple code:

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead" />

var source = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
    source: source })
```

jsfiddle:  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/457/)

What am I doing wrong?  (note my js is at the bottom of the jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You're using a different version of `typeahead.js` than how you're calling it.

The latest version of `typeahead` expects a variable number of dataset arguments. See my updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/458/

```
var source = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];

function mySource(query, callback){
  srcs = [];
  for(var idx in source){
      var src = source[idx];
      if(src.indexOf(query) !== -1){
        srcs.push({value: src});
      }
  }
  console.log(srcs);
  callback(srcs);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    var t = $(".typeahead");
    t.typeahead({}, {'source': mySource});
});
```

For each dataset, there needs to be a `source` attribute that points to a function. That function takes the query string and a callback function. It is expected that you do what you need with the query string and then call the callback function with a list of objects where each object has an attribute of `value` that maps to the value to display.

I *think* you should be able to specify `{'local': source}` in the options, but I haven't gotten it to work.

Anyway, if you want the old API, you'll have to use Bootstrap 2's version of typeahead.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Do you know why the styling is inconsistent with that of the typeahead demo page?  It seems like a bunch of css is missing.

Comment: Where is this usage syntax documented?  I can't figure out how to customize the matcher/updater/highlighter methods with this syntax.